# I am getting error on using http-server on my pixijs game and it is saying "cannot import statement outside module" and i want to use npm only

Tags: server, frameworks, game-engine, game-development, pixi.js

I created simple folder and using npm, I installed packages of pixi.js. Created html and js file. Then I copied some of the code from internet as simple as it could be. And using http-server, I am getting error on "cannot use import statement outside the module". I am beginner in the pixijs.

```
import * as PIXI from "pixi.js";

// application initialisation
const app = new PIXI.Application({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  backgroundColor: 0x1099bb,
});

document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// text
const text = new PIXI.Text("Hello, world!");

text.x = 200;
text.y = 200;
text.style.fill = 0xffffff;

app.stage.addChild(text);

// graphic
const graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();

graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
graphics.drawRect(300, 300, 100, 100);
graphics.endFill();

app.stage.addChild(graphics);
```

**Showing error on the import statement.**